# Old() function in laravel collective form

Tags: php, laravel-6, laravelcollective

Good morinig everyone.
Can you tell me how to use the old() function in laravel collective?
- classical form:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{old('username')}} />
```

But with laravelcollective form, I don't know how to do. Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use old() in laravel collective form simply apply this method:

**{{ Form::text('name',old('name'),['type'=>'text','class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Name']) }}**

Be noted that you can also use old() in Controller by below mentioned method:

**$email = $request->old('name');** *(but remember that you need to declare Request Object in your function parameter where you redirect after submit. eg: **public function add(Request $request) {}** )*

Answer (score 0):

hello Crispus Elischama,
In my case, I am using this way...

```
{{ Form::email('email', old('email'), ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Email']) }}
```

and use [withInput()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41186213/laravel-5-3-forms-not-retaining-old-input-when-validation-fails) end of the route

```
return redirect()->back()->withInput();
```